# Sending email email using SSL not work in my Java Application, TLS work

Tags: java, ssl, jakarta-mail

This is SendMailTLS.java. **This work.**

```
    Properties props = new Properties();

    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");     

    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    //props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.gmail.com"); //if avast is enabled

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
      new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }
    });

    try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
            InternetAddress.parse(recipient));
        message.setSubject("TLS");
        message.setText("TLS");

        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

This is SendMailSSL.java. **This doesn't work.**

```
Properties props = new Properties();

    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
      new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }
    });

    try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
            InternetAddress.parse(recipient));
        message.setSubject("SSL");
        message.setText("SSL");

        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

Both classes import:

```
    import java.util.Properties; 
    import javax.mail.Message;
    import javax.mail.MessagingException;
    import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
    import javax.mail.Session;
    import javax.mail.Transport;
    import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
    import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
```

I don't understand what the code does so if someone could help explain it for me.. Is there something that i done wrong in the SSL file? And do i need to worry about the TLS version if i'm using java mail API?

Comment: doesn't work..? does it give any exception?? what are the changes you have tried?? please elaborate..

Comment: "doesn't work" : when i run the program (the SSL one), the email didn't get delivered.

Comment: Surely there was an exception? Don't be coy.

Comment: The program run forever man. I dunno what happen. Can u try the code yourself?

Answer (score 1):

Start by fixing these [common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).  Then explain what "doesn't work" means, perhaps by including the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug).

Since you're having trouble figuring out how to fix the [common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes) yourself, try changing the code to this:

```
Properties props = new Properties();

props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");

Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
session.setDebug(true);

try {

    Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
        InternetAddress.parse(recipient));
    message.setSubject("SSL");
    message.setText("SSL");

    Transport.send(message, username, password);

    System.out.println("Done");

} catch (MessagingException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

If that doesn't work, post the [debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) (enabled above) and try the [connection debugging tips](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug) and report the results.

Comment: "doesn't work" : when i run the program (the SSL one), the email didn't get delivered.

Comment: Again, what does the debug output show?  Did you fix the common mistakes?  Are you getting an Exception?

Comment: I don't see common mistakes there. When I run it on netbeans, it runs forever and never stop. Can you try the code yourself?

Answer (score 0):

> Sending email email using SSL not work in my Java Application, TLS work

You are mistaken. The salient differences are these:

```
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
```

*versus*

```
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
```

and

```
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
```

*versus*

```
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
```

Neither of these has anything to do with SSL versus TLS. What you are seeing is the difference between ports 587 and 465, and between STARTTLS starting from an initial plaintext connection *versus* an initial TLS connection.

Comment: i just followed [this example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/). what i know about tls is that this is the newer version of ssl.

Comment: No it in't. Both version use TLS or SSL equally, depending in what the peer negotiates. The differences are what I stated, nothing else.

Comment: Do you say that the example is misleading?